# Forbid npm unpublish on client computer

Tags: npm, verdaccio

Hello I would like to know if a special npm configuration could

- enable npm publish
- disable npm unpublish  --force [IDEAL]
- disable all npm unpublish commands

I am using Verdaccio as a private package repository, and I know that they are working on a special configuration that can achieve this. But does that feature/configuration exist already on client computer using npm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is available in Verdaccio since `v4.0.0-alpha.5`

https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/blob/4.x/CHANGELOG.md#features

For instance

```
 'vue':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: admin
    proxy: npmjs
```

We are introducing a new property called `unpublish` to be able to handle such a situation. For backward compatibility, if `unpublish` is not defined will be relying on `publish` as it works in previous versions.

For more info check our docs

https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/packages#unpublishing-packages

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. Yes I am aware of this POC, I also asked them for a date but no answer yet :) I am just exploring another way which is to tune the developer computer so he CANNOT use unpublish --force

Comment: It will be part of V4 really soon, check our milestone https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/milestone/15

Comment: AH ok that's awsome April 30 apparently ! Thank's a lot for the information. In the mean time if you know about another way, Dont hesitate communicate I will come back here to mark your answer as accepted when I managed to secure npm unpublish --force

Comment: Sure, fair enough :-) (April 30 is our deadline), next alpha will be released next week)

Comment: Waw very nice ! I am gonna try to use this, but it's my client who owns their Verdaccio so I am not sure if the will accept to use alpha version :) (giving you maximum point so you can create Verdaccio tag lol)

Comment: Hello again, they wont use the alpha version :) we'll wait until April 30 :) In the mean time I hope I can try another (but the best is the upcoming Verdaccio version)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Juan Picado ! https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/releases Is this just the 4.0.0.alpha.5 that is released ? I am sorry I didnt catch the time to be able to try this :( And the client won't test the alpha, he will wait for the RC

Comment: Not working for the same client. But I forward the info to related teams. Anyway I use a Verdaccio in MY company, so i'll try new version and the feature. Thanks for the followup